# Apply Style to change text color and size

Tags: html

Three files are given. The third one shows you what your finished web page should look like. The two others should be included in the main file created by you. Your web page should accommodate the following:
..Don't allow the same color chosen for both the text color and cell color. Show an alert message if so chosen.
..Add an option for the font size to change among 3, 5, and 7.

```
    <html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
  <form name="StyleForm">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" height="40" valign="top">
          <b>STYLES</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>
            <font size="2">Text Color:</font><br>
            <select name="TextColor">
              <option value="">- select -</option>
              <option value="black">Black</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
              <option value="white">White</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font size="2">Cell Color:</font><br>
            <select name="CellColor">
              <option value="">- select -</option>
              <option value="black">Black</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
              <option value="white">White</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Apply Style">
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>


<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font size="3"><b>STYLE VIEWER</b></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="100" width="400" style="background-color:white">
        <div style="color:black">
          <font size="5">Hello World Wide Web!</font>
        <div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my code, it just not applying the style

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<script>
function apply_style();

{
var TextColor = LeftFrame.document.StyleForm.TextColor.value;
var CellColor = LeftFrame.document.StyleForm.CellColor.value;
var TextElement = RightFrame.document.getElementById("MessageText");
textElement.style.color = textColor;
cellElement.style.backgroundColor = cellColor; return;
}
</script>
</head>
<frameset cols="30%,*">
<frame src="left1.html">
<frame src="right1.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not how it works, you have to do your own homework. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: You should post what you've tried

Comment: I have post my code, please help :(

Comment: If apply_style is a function declaration, one thing you could do to improve would be putting your logic within the brackets:  function apply_style() { // logic }. You'll want to call your function afterwards, if I understand what you're doing: apply_style()

Comment: Side note, don't use tables for layout and don't use the `<font>` or `<frameset>` tags

Comment: What does a frame.document do even?

Answer (score 0):

First, to use getElementById you actually need to have an element with the id you want. Second, you should call your function otherwise it will not do anything. Third you missed getting your cell element.

Here's a code and try to study it:

```js
function apply_style() {
  var textColor = document.getElementById('TextColor').value;
  var cellColor = document.getElementById('CellColor').value;
  var textElement = document.getElementById("MessageText");
  var cellElement = document.getElementById("cell");
  textElement.style.color = textColor;
  cellElement.style.backgroundColor = cellColor; 
}
```

```html
 <html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
  <form name="StyleForm">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" height="40" valign="top">
          <b>STYLES</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>
            <font size="2">Text Color:</font><br>
            <select id="TextColor" name="TextColor">
              <option value="">- select -</option>
              <option value="black">Black</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
              <option value="white">White</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font size="2">Cell Color:</font><br>
            <select id="CellColor" name="CellColor">
              <option value="">- select -</option>
              <option value="black">Black</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
              <option value="white">White</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="button" id="button" onclick="apply_style()"value="Apply Style">
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>


<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font size="3"><b>STYLE VIEWER</b></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell" align="center" height="100" width="400" style="background-color:white">
        <div style="color:black">
          <font id="MessageText" size="5">Hello World Wide Web!</font>
        <div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```